# Spring Cloud Netflix | Eureka not registering when deployed on ECS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka

I am trying to deploy Spring Netflix Eureka and related microservice application using ECS and Cloudformation.

Eureka is not able to register the related microservices because the docker images are not able to link on hostname.

Please suggest what should be the best solution to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use EC2 instance's host ip instead of docker container host's. In your microservices (if those are spring boot applications), put this code:

```
@Bean
@Profile("docker")
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig() {
    EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean();
    AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
    config.setDataCenterInfo(info);
    info.getMetadata().put(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicHostname.getName(), info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicIpv4));
    config.setHostname(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicHostname));
    config.setIpAddress(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicIpv4));
    config.setNonSecurePort(port);
    return config;
}
```

Remember to enable 'docker' profile in spring boot configuration.

Comment: Should I put the above code in eureka app or in zuul app or in the microservice app?

Comment: in the microservice application which will register to eureka.